# Android reading content from web

Tags: android, multithreading

Version 1

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(reader);
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        result = total.toString();
        return result;

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }
  }
}
```

Version 2

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            result += current;
        data = reader.read();
        }
        result = total.toString();
        return result;

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }
  }
```

}

Basically, I am trying to read the HTML contents of a website by extending the `AsynTask`. The only difference between the 2 codes is the way I am reading and returning the contents as a string. Version 1 **DOES NOT** work but version 2 works. My question is why does version 1 not work? I am storing the contents in the buffer reader and putting it into a `StringBuilder` and displaying it as a string as shown.

Comment: Okay i just tried it a couple of times and version 1 works sometimes but version 2 works most of the time. Is there any logical explanation for this? thank you

Comment: What do you means by not working? Does it throw an expection? or the stream is empty?

Comment: Debug it and you'll know.

Comment: @m0skit0 I did not encounter any problems. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Joshua I'm asking the OP.